# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not type

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a submarine game in python, but when I try to run it, the interpreter gives me very strange error:
"TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not type."
I tried to search the web for my answer, but it seems like this isn't very usual error. I also tried to find error by myself, but everything   seemed fine to me. Here 's  part of the code that I think error is in:

```
mina = pygame.image.load('mina.png')
class mina():
    def __init__(self, x , y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.eksplozija = False
    def naris(self):
        screen.blit(mina, (self.x, self.y))
igralec = podmornica(150, 300, 10)
eksploziv = mina(700, 350)
metki = []
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
def grafika():
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.blit(ozadje, (0,0))
    igralec.naris()
    #line, that doesn't work:
    eksploziv.naris()
    for metek in metki:
        metek.naris(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You overwrote the image named `mina`, that would have been a valid first parameter for the `.blit()` method, with a class of the same name.

Comment: Change the name of the class `mina` -> `class Mina:`, `eksploziv = Mina(700, 350)`

Comment: Now it works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `mina` and the class `mina` have the same name. The class `mina` shadows the variable `mina`. You need to rename one or the other. I recommend to rename the calss `mina` to `Mina`, since Python classes use the CapWords convention ([PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)):

<s>`class mina():`</s>

```py
class Mina():
```

<s>`eksploziv = mina(700, 350)`</s>

```py
eksploziv = Mina(700, 350)
```